# Word search in SQL Server tables

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, intellij-idea

How to search for a word in all tables. To output all the tables where this word is available.

I use IDEA for queries.

The problem is that there are more than 300 + tables. Need to find the tables in which this word is present.

For example, there is a Phone number table and there is a number column in it, I need to find a value from the number column, for example row 3045636

Comment: Could you tell us if you are looking for a *word* as a column value or for a *word* in column names or table names?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: For example, there is a Phone number table and there is a number column in it, I need to find a value from the number column, for example row 3045636

Comment: @xXx  I tried to get the code from [here](https://remotehelper.ru/subd/ms-sql-server/ms-sql-server-poisk-guid-po-vsem-tablitsam-bd)

Comment: please evaluate the similar question you found so we can understand what you are trying to achieve. You could not understand them, we can't understand what you understand

Comment: @Blacit : check this link : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1522/searching-and-finding-a-string-value-in-all-columns-in-a-sql-server-table/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the approach I suggest:

1. Read all table name from database
2. Read all column name from individual table wise
3. Search for word in each table of each column

```
#Table Names
select table_name
from information_schema.tables
where table_type = 'base table' and table_catalog='dbname'

#Column Names
select column_name 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name like 'table name'

#Word Search
select count(*) from table_name where column_name1 like 'searchWord' or column_name2 like 'searchWord'
```

All those things you have to integrate inside procedure so in final if count(*)>1 that table contain particular word.

Comment: Can you tell me what should be in place: base table - the name of the table?, dbname - the name of the scheme in which I am looking?

Comment: keep it as it is.

Comment: in the second stage, too, nothing to touch? And on the third lit red table_name, column_name1, column_name2. What is there to set up? I need to find among all the tables the word 3045636

Comment: I'm sorry that I'm stupid, but how to do it through idea? In the Java language?

Comment: In java you have to establish jdbc connection to database and perform above queries. The query data you have to store temporary somewhere to perform your other actions. Read about java jdbc with MS sql or if your using spring boot then its quite simple use jpa for that with custom query

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1
You could write a dynamic query and use loop.

In first loop get all the tables and load all string data type column and frame the select query and find the value and store output as intermediate table .

Solution 2
You could use a power shell script.